# From a bigquery output a vendor wants each line to end with a delimiter

Tags: select, google-bigquery, export-to-csv

We are running a bigquery select, setting the delimiter to '|'.
Then vendor requires each line, including header, end with the delimiter
I can force a '|' on each data row, how can I force the header to head with a | also?
For example
select a as A, b as B, '|' from xyz
this will output
A|B|f0_
a|b|
f0_ needs to be |

Comment: Field/column name must contain only letters, numbers, and underscores, start with a letter or underscore, and be at most 128 characters long.

Comment: So there is not a way to escape a special character to use it as a header name

Comment: if you want to use pipe char as an alias in select statement - 'no way', but header name is not always a column/field name  - right? you need to better explain your use case - what exactly you mean by header and why pipe is needed there and how it is then used, etc.

Comment: We have a csv file we ship to a vendor.  This file was built in Teradata, we have now migrated to BigQuery. The vendor requires the csv file be formated as
COL1|COL2|COL3|
data1|data2|data3|
therefore I need to format out BQ csv file the same, ending with a '|'.
Because of the company process for extracting BQ, we can not process file once it has been generated.

Comment: Never did figure out how to achieve this.  Wound up inserting a simple sed command to do the append.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [bq extract --field_delimiter](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference#bq_extract) in your case you can use this [command](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#exporting_table_data):

bq --location=US extract --field_delimiter '|' 'DATASET.TABLE' gs://BUGCKET/myfile.csv

Comment: I wound up running the output through a sed script to append a pipe to end each line.